# XML to csv conversion in xslt-1.0 using exslt:node-set()

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm looking to convert my input xml to csv output with help of xslt-1.0 . 
Below is my **input xml** format.

```
     <input>
     <add add-value="First Name">
        <value type="string">New</value>
      </add>
       <add add-value="Surname">
        <value  type="string">user1</value>
      </add>
      <add add-value="Title">
        <value type="string">engineer</value>
     </add>
     <add add-value="Description">
        <value type="string">New joinee.</value>
      </add>
<add .....
</add>
    </input>
```

The output csv consists of fixed number of columns which i'm providing through variable in xslt.

**Below is my xslt:**

```
     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" >   
        <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>   
        <xsl:template match="input/add">
            <xsl:variable name="SplitWordsSet">
                <xsl:call-template name="split">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="'First name,Surname,Phone number,Description,Title'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="vSplitWords" select="ext:node-set($SplitWordsSet)/*"/>

            <xsl:call-template name="counter">
                <xsl:with-param name="split-words" select="$vSplitWords"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="count"select="1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:template> 
<!-- Below templtate splits the pText values -->
        <xsl:template name="split">
            <xsl:param name="pText"/>
            <xsl:param name="pElemName" select="'word'"/>
            <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-before(concat($pText,','),',')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($pText,',')"/>
            <xsl:element name="{$pElemName}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$first"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$remaining">
                    <xsl:call-template name="split">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$remaining"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pElemName" select="$pElemName"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template> 
<!-- below is recursive template to maintain count of columns values -->
        <xsl:template name="counter">
            <xsl:param name="count" select="1"/>
            <xsl:param name="split-words"/>
            <xsl:variable name="split-word" select="$split-words[$count]"/>
            <xsl:if test="$count &lt; 6">
                <xsl:call-template name="output-csv">
                    <xsl:with-param name="field-value" select="*[(@add-value = '$split-word')]/value"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="counter">
                    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>     
        <xsl:template name="output-csv">
            <xsl:param name="field-value"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$field-value"/>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The add-value attributes which i'm interested in is passed as `pText` param.These values are my columns in output csv.

My expected output:

```
First name,Surname,Phone number,Description,Title
New,User1,,New joinee,engineer
```

But i'm not able to get the desired output.I get only the comma's `,,,,,`
Please somebody point out where i'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of problems in your XSLT. Firstly, with your initial template match, you are matching on **add** elements, but as it is an **input** element that represents a line in your CSV file, you probably want to match on that

```
<xsl:template match="input">
```

Then, when you call your **output-csv** template, you should be looking for the **add** element with the corrent **add-value** attribute for the current words.

```
<xsl:call-template name="output-csv">
   <xsl:with-param name="field-value" select="add[@add-value = $split-word]/value"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Your main problem though is with how you recursively call the **counter** template. You are not re-setting the **split-words** attribute here, so on the second call, the parameter will be empty.

```
 <xsl:call-template name="counter">
    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
 </xsl:call-template>
```

(It might be also worth pointing out that in your XML you have the first attribute as 'First Name', but in your list of column names in the XSLT, it is 'first name'. The string comparison in XSLT is case-senstive).

You could just set the parameter here, but it might be better (certainly more efficient) to make your list of split words a global variable, rather than split them for each **input** element.

Try this XSLT

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ext="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" >   
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>
   <xsl:variable name="SplitWordsSet">
     <xsl:call-template name="split">
       <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="'First name,Surname,Phone number,Description,Title'"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:variable name="vSplitWords" select="ext:node-set($SplitWordsSet)/*"/>

    <xsl:template match="input">
        <xsl:call-template name="counter">
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template> 

  <!-- Below templtate splits the pText values -->
    <xsl:template name="split">
        <xsl:param name="pText"/>
        <xsl:param name="pElemName" select="'word'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-before(concat($pText,','),',')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($pText,',')"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$pElemName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$first"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$remaining">
                <xsl:call-template name="split">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$remaining"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pElemName" select="$pElemName"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

 <!-- below is recursive template to maintain count of columns values -->
    <xsl:template name="counter">
        <xsl:param name="count" select="1"/>
        <xsl:param name="split-words"/>

        <xsl:variable name="split-word" select="$vSplitWords[$count]"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="output-csv">
          <xsl:with-param name="field-value" select="add[@add-value = $split-word]/value"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:if test="$count &lt; 5">
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="counter">
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>     
    <xsl:template name="output-csv">
        <xsl:param name="field-value"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$field-value"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should give you the output

```
 New,user1,,New joinee.,engineer
```

However, there is another approach you can take, without using recursively template. Have a template that matches your split **word** elements, passing in the current **input** as a parameter

```
   <xsl:template match="word">
     <xsl:param name="input" />
     <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
       <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
     </xsl:if>
     <xsl:value-of select="$input/add[@add-value = current()]/value" />
   </xsl:template>
```

Then, each line can be output like so

```
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$vSplitWords">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="." />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
```

Try this XSLT too

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ext="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" >   
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

   <xsl:variable name="SplitWordsSet">
     <xsl:call-template name="split">
       <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="'First name,Surname,Phone number,Description,Title'"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:variable name="vSplitWords" select="ext:node-set($SplitWordsSet)/*"/>

    <xsl:template match="input">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$vSplitWords">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="." />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template> 

 <!-- Below templtate splits the pText values -->
    <xsl:template name="split">
        <xsl:param name="pText"/>
        <xsl:param name="pElemName" select="'word'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-before(concat($pText,','),',')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($pText,',')"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$pElemName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$first"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$remaining">
                <xsl:call-template name="split">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$remaining"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pElemName" select="$pElemName"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="word">
     <xsl:param name="input" />
     <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
       <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
     </xsl:if>
     <xsl:value-of select="$input/add[@add-value = current()]/value" />
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```